# Creating a JavaScript Stub Class From WSDL

Tags: javascript, wsdl

I realize this may seem like a duplicate, but I've read the other post and it wasn't entirely helpful.

I'm researching a project wherein I will need to make a SOAP web services call from server-side running on a JavaScript engine that acts essentially as a Java wrapper on top of an Oracle database (so, use JavaScript files and APIs, they call back into Java code and pull data from Oracle). I'm familiar with generating WSDL stub files for C# in Visual Studio and I've used tools to do so for Java/Android. However, I'm having trouble with accomplishing this for JavaScript.

I've been putzing with Apache CXF for this, but the results require some other library file which I cannot seem to find. Plus, I have to remove several instances of 'maxOccur' attributes from a series of 'element' elements because they cause a bunch of errors while processing the WSDL.

On top of this, I would have to replace any actual AJAX calls with the system API for such calls, as their JavaScript engine doesn't support those particular functions (you know, since they provided one to be used). This almost seems possible with the actual CXF-generated file, but it still makes calls to an outside library which I cannot locate (in the initialization method, I see this: this.jsutils = new CxfApacheOrgUtil(); ).

Is there a good option for this? Or am I better off try to get some SOAP XML samples and parsing out tags in a predefined text string? Or maybe another option I don't yet realize?

I should also mention I checked out an option on CodeProject, but it hasn't been updated since 2007-2008, and I don't think it'll fit what I'm trying to do, anyway.

**-- EDIT --**

I've been doing some testing with the WSDL, and I don't know if this means anything, maybe better for a completely different post altogether, but here's the chunk that throws the error when processing the WSDL...

```
   <complexType name="AuthenticationToken">
    <sequence>
     <element name="loginId" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="password" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="licenseKey" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
     <element name="accountNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <element name="AuthenticationToken" type="impl:AuthenticationToken" maxOccurs="1"/>
```

It was easier to understand which spot where "maxOccurs" was being used when I tried importing the WSDL into a .NET project using Visual Studio. When either removing that attribute completely, or moving it to the above "complexType" element, the WSDL was able to be processed without error. I'm not sure, really, what effect either of those changes actually has on the generated stub class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was finally able to find the required library file to use with the stub file generated via Apache CXF. I also determined how I can just add my own additional components to the stub in order to handle the use of the APIs for making AJAX calls within this system (not the most familiar with creating and modifying "Classes" within JavaScript, so it was rather daunting at first).

I'm still not sure what to do about that "maxOccurs" attribute, but I suppose I can see what the development team for those web services has to say about the errors I encountered, now that I have been able to get in contact with them.